# Add "discount" to invoice PDF

Tags: invoice

When I view an invoice I can see if a discount was applied to each line item.  However when I print the PDF for it I do not get the discount as a line item but just a total.  I see my table headers in:

`/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`

May I ask what my "feed" number is for discounts? Also is this the only file that I need to copy over to local to edit?

Comment: add the picture of your invoice to see how discount shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up purchasing an extension from @FoomanNZ.  The extension lets you customize in great detail the look of the PDF.  It also gives a solid admin interface for your customers to alter. It is called Fooman PDFs Customiser. On his site it has several positive reviews.

Comment: Please provide some details about what the extension does, and mark the answer as accepted.